# Find with exec not working as expected

Tags: find

I need to check if folder exist and if yes make an action or if not make another action. I use find for this task but I can't figured out the proper way:

```
find /path/to/destination -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "dir*" -exec bash -c '[[ $1 ]] && echo ok || echo "not ok"' _ {} \;
```

but or part in bash seciton is newer executed, any suggestions why ?

Comment: Since the `-exec` will always pass a non-empty `{}`, `[[ $1 ]]` will always be non-null (therefore true), no?

Comment: Seems this is impossible with find ... ?

Comment: You don't need the script to see if it exists; `find` will only find things that exist. Your `[[ $1 ]]` test is only checking to see if there's a string there, not "if a folder exists"; what's your real test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if there are any directories matching that name pattern, you could have `find` print some dummy output for them, and see if the output was empty. E.g.:

```
if [[ "$(find -type d -name "dir*" -printf .)" ]] ; then
    echo "some matching directory exists"
else 
    echo "no matching directory exists"
fi
```

You could also have `find` execute a command for the files it found, by just adding the `-exec bash -c '...' _ {} \;` after the `-printf`. If the command doesn't produce any output, this should be fine.

It does get a bit worse if you need to capture output from the command started by `find` and keep it separate from the dummy output: you'll need temporary files or redirection trickery. This should run `somecmd` on any directories matched by `find`, directing the output of the `somecmd` executions to the scripts stdout, and then tell you if there were any matches.

```
exec 3>&1
any=$(find -type d -name "dir*" -printf . -exec bash -c 'somecmd "$1" >&3' _ {} \; )
if [[ "$any" ]] ; then
    echo "matching directories were processed"
else 
    echo "no matching directory exists"
fi
exec 3>&-
```

Of course, if the command started by `find` *always* produces output, there's no need the dummy output. Just capture whatever `find` prints, and see if it was empty.

Answer (score 3):

The `-exec` will only be done for files that match the previous criteria (`-name 'dir*'` and `-type d`), and once for each file.

Here, you'd probably want to use `zsh` and do something like:

```
dirs=(/path/to/destination/dir*(N/))
if (($#dirs)); then
  echo Found these dirs:
  printf ' - %s\n' $dirs
else
  echo >&2 No dir found
fi
```

Or with bash version 4.4 or  above and GNU `find` of compatible (which you must already  be using as you're using the `-maxdepth` GNU extension):

```
readarray -td '' dirs < <(
  find /path/to/destination -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "dir*" -print0)

if ((${#dirs[@]})); then
  echo Found these dirs:
  printf ' - %s\n' "${dirs[@]}"
else
  echo >&2 No dir found
fi
```

Comment: I was trying to do it only with find with shortest and simplest way but seems it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but in bash:

```
(shopt -s nullglob; if ! [ -z /path/to/destination/dir*/ ] 2>&-; then  echo ok; else echo not ok; fi)
```

With `nullglob` enabled, `/path/to/destination/dir*/` will expand to:

- nothing if no matching directories were found, in which case the `-z` test succeeds, and so the negated test fails;
- or to the list of all matching directories, in which case:

  - if there's only one directory, the `-z` test fails
  - if there are multiple directories, the test command fails since `-z` expects only one operand

  and so the negated test passes.

Examples:

```
$ if ! [ -z /a* ] 2>&-; then  echo ok; else echo not ok; fi
not ok
$ if ! [ -z /b* ] 2>&-; then  echo ok; else echo not ok; fi # multiple: /bin /boot 
ok
$ if ! [ -z /h* ] 2>&-; then  echo ok; else echo not ok; fi # single: /home
ok
```

This is one case where the extended test can't be used, since globbing doesn't happen in `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: Note that the expansion of `/path/to/destination/dir*/` includes symlinks to directories. It's different from `find`'s `-type d` or `zsh`'s `/path/to/destination/dir*(/)`. It's more like GNU `find`'s `-xtype d` or `zsh`'s `/path/to/destination/dir*(-/)`. That may be just as well for the OP though.